# How to get data from a website in xml format and parse that data to do stuff using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser, nsxml

I want to get the data from the website careercup.com in xml format and parse that using objective c and hopefully load some resulting data onto a plist file. Could anyone guide me on how to go about doing this? Meaning how to get the data from the website in xml format and once I have gotten the data, where do I store it so that I can then parse it and load whatever I need into my plist file. I would like to tackle the problem of getting the website data in xml format and storing it first. As I know the parsing can be achieved using NSXML parser and so on. But I would like to know how to retrieve website in xml format and then where to store this retrieved xml data so that I can parse it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very good example for what you need http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial

For more advance look at the available xml parsers For ios you can have a look at this http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Both links will give you a quick push to develop your ideas!